# Deploying Static Private Files in .NET5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

My project's `sln` file is located at `C:\ProjectName\`, and the API project is located at `C:\ProjectName\Project.Api\`.

I have a static folder, in which I store some files that are needed for a successful build and launch which is located at this path `C:\ProjectName\Project.Api\LaunchFiles\launchFileOne.json`. But when I get a build, the `bin\debug\net5.0\` folder does not have the `LaunchFiles\` directory. In order for me to successfully do a deploy of this app, I need to have the `LaunchFiles\` directory deployed under `bin\debug\net5.0`.

How can I achieve this? I cannot use  `wwwroot` for this purpose since these files need to be private and not open to access. IIS directory browsing will be off, so no problem on that case.

Comment: Have you added the file to your project and set the "Copy to Output Directory"-property?

Comment: Oh, I found the answer based on yours. Adding few lines into `.csproj` helped me to do so. Would you like to post an answer so that I can accept it? @JonasH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy some kind of arbitrary data file with your program you need to first add it to the solution, then set the **Copy to Output Directory**-property. This is "do not copy" by default.

[image]